# VBA code to find and replace using maybe wildcard?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I find and remove X from strings, in other words, replace NX1 with N1, NX2 with N2, NX7535 with N7535, all strings start with N but not all have X after N, if they do I need to remove that X, Below I put crazy code I adapted from excel recording but it has to be easier way to do it:

```
   Sub Find_NX_Replace()



     Range("A1").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
     Selection.Replace What:="NX1", Replacement:="N1", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="NX2", Replacement:="N2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

     Selection.Replace What:="NX3", Replacement:="N3", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

 Selection.Replace What:="NX4", Replacement:="N4", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

     Selection.Replace What:="NX5", Replacement:="N5", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="NX6", Replacement:="N6", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

     Selection.Replace What:="NX7", Replacement:="N7", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Selection.Replace What:="NX8", Replacement:="N8", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False


     Selection.Replace What:="NX9", Replacement:="N9", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False




   End Sub
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a loop of the number:

```
Sub Find_NX_Replace()
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 1 To 9
        Selection.Replace What:="NX" & i, Replacement:="N" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to remove X only when after X is number, your code would work with NX566 but if I have NX2447NX it would change it to N2447N, To clarify X in cells which has to be removed is always as the second character in every cell

Comment: You need to put that information in the Original Post.